# removing a document by passing its id using form_tag

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Let's say I have book model, book.rb

```
class Book
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :book_id, type: String
  field :title, type: String
end
```

*(Here I'm using mongoid, but I think for this question it doesn't matter what type of data is.)*

The `book` model has its own controller, views, etc.

Now, I want to create a page with form_tag (let me know if this is not a proper way), where by entering book's id and clicking enter I'll be able to remove the record this this given id from the database.

remove.html.erb:

```
<%= form_tag books_path, :method => 'get' do %>
<p>book_id:
    <%= text_field_tag :book_id, params[:book_id] %>
    <%= submit_tag "Remove", :name => nil, :confirm => "Are you sure?" %>
</p>
<% end %>
```

I know how to remove a given document, but can't figure out how to pass the value entered in the form and where to put the logic that will remove document.

[image]

Comment: don't ever use a GET request for deleting things :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First things first. Why do you need to store a `book_id` for your `Book` model ? Mongoid already provide a `_id` field for this purpose.

The usual way to destroy resources is to hit the destroy action in your controller by making a DELETE HTTP request.

```
class BooksController
  def destroy
    Book.find(params[:id]).destroy
    redirect_to :back
  end
end
```

Then simply do a link with the following:

```
link_to "Delete", book_path(@book), method: :delete
```

Where `@book` is your book instance.

Comment: Thanks. I'm aware of "_id" field in mongodb. It was just an example given here. But what if I want to do other operations than simply deleting. Is controller still the best place to put such logic?

Comment: Depending on your needs, you should follow the "skinny controllers, fat models" rails principle. Controller should only be responsible for rendering and calling your instances methods. Put your logic in models.

Comment: The one line code you showed, should I just add it to my remove.html.erb code? If I'm misunderstanding could you please show it together with my code?

Comment: Yes, the `link_to` should go to one of your views. Usually you want to loop on every `@books` you may have and show your book details and actions (edit, delete) for example.

Comment: I think what you mean can be done by using a scaffold feature which will arrange all of this stuff. But my question was how can I perform a remove action using form_tag I described on my post. It won't be show view but a separate page, for example, remove.html.erb.

Comment: If you really want to perform the destroy action using a `form_tag` simply do this `form_tag book_path(@book), method: :delete`